# Configuration of tibco jms with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jms, tibco

Now I have java code which starts tibco jms subscription with several steps:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("java.naming.provider.url", namingProvider);
        props.put("java.naming.factory.initial", namingFactory);
        props.put("java.naming.referral", namingReferral);
        props.put("java.naming.security.credentials", securityCredentials);
        props.put("java.naming.security.principal", securityPrincipal);

        context = new InitialContext(props);
        TopicConnectionFactory tfactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context
                .lookup(url + topic + ":tcf");

        topicConnection = tfactory.createTopicConnection(user, password);
        topicConnection.setExceptionListener(exceptionListener);
        topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);      
        subscriber = topicSession.createSubscriber(
                (Topic) context.lookup(url + topic + ":topic"),
                SELECTOR, true); 
        subscriber.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        topicConnection.start();
```

I want to use Spring for initialization, but I can't find how to configure jms in spring using initial context. 
Can you help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this to get TopicConnectionFactory:

```
<bean id="tfactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="url/topic:tcf"/>
  <property name="jndiEnvironment">
    <props>
      <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">...</prop>
      <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">...</prop>
      <prop key="java.naming.referral">...</prop>
      <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">...</prop>
      <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">...</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 9):

Good Day Friends,

**Step 1:**

As of today you have to be registered to use https://download.tibco.com/tibco.

You can download a trial of EMS at 
http://tap.tibco.com/storefront/trialware/tibco-enterprise-message-service/prod15032.html. Once you install the trial the jars will be in the **ems/8.0/lib** directory.

**Step 2:**

**Tibco jar files are not available @ Maven Repository.**

Collect all tibco jar files from tibco ems installables.

1. jms.jar -  ***Available @ Maven repo***
2. tibjms.jar
3. tibcrypt.jar (For SSL)
4. tibemsd_sec.jar
5. tibjms.jar
6. tibjmsadmin.jar
7. tibjmsapps.jar
8. tibjmsufo.jar
9. tibrvjms.jar
10. spring-jms.jar  - ***Available @ Maven repo***

Execute below command from command prompt to include tibco jars into local maven repository.

**Step 3:**

**Commands:**

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.jms -DartifactId=jms -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=jms.jar
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tibco -DartifactId=tibcrypt -Dversion=5.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tibcrypt.jar
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tibco -DartifactId=tibemsd_sec -Dversion=5.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tibemsd_sec.jar
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tibco -DartifactId=tibjms -Dversion=5.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tibjms.jar
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tibco -DartifactId=tibjmsadmin -Dversion=5.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tibjmsadmin.jar
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tibco -DartifactId=tibjmsapps -Dversion=5.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tibjmsapps.jar
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tibco -DartifactId=tibjmsufo -Dversion=5.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tibjmsufo.jar
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.tibco -DartifactId=tibrvjms -Dversion=5.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tibrvjms.jar

**Maven Dependencies for Tibco EMS. Add it on you .pom file dependencies**

```
         <!-- Tibco EMS Start -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibemsd_sec</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibjmsadmin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibjmsapps</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibjmsufo</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibrvjms</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tibco EMS End -->
```

**Shown is the Spring file for tibco config.**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<context:property-placeholder
    location="file:${user.home}/config.properties"
    ignore-resource-not-found="true" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.ems" />

<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx</prop> <!--dynamic depending on your project-->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="QueueConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
    class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="xxxxxx" />  <!--dynamic depending on your project-->
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="xxxxxx" /> <!--dynamic depending on your project-->
    <property name="password" value="xxxxxx" /> <!--dynamic depending on your project-->
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="authenticationConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination" />
</bean>

<bean id="logger" class="com.mycompany.ems.Logger" />
```

**Java File Implementation**

```
package com.mycompany.ems;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


/**
 * @author Parthasarathy Balakrishnan
 * @description sends tibco queue message from this class
 *
 */
@Component
public class Logger{

private final static Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(Logger .class);


private static JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;


/**
 * 
 */
public Logger() {
}

/**
 * @param <T>
 * @param args
 * @author Parthasarathy Balakrishnan
 * 
 */
public static <T> void log(Class<T> clazz, Object message, Throwable t) {

    try {

        JMSSend("PROJECT_QUEUE_NAME", clazz, message, t);
        logger.debug("Message Sent...");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

/**
 * @param Queue
 * @param clazz
 * @param message
 * @param t
 * @Description It uses org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate to send JMS message to tibco Queue.
 * @author Parthasarathy Balakrishnan
 */
static <T> void JMSSend(String Queue, final Class<T> clazz, final Object message,
        final Throwable t) {
    jmsTemplate.send(Queue, new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage sendMessage = session
                    .createTextMessage("<xml>send message</xml>");
            return sendMessage;
        }
    });
}


/**
 * @return
 */
public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate() {
    return jmsTemplate;
}

/**
 * @param jmsTemplate
 */
@Autowired
public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    BsfLogger.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

}
```

It is working for me, Please ping me in case of any exceptions.

Comment: How do i invoke the ems message sender

Comment: Please take a look at JMSSend method in the class Logger.java

Comment: Works for me ... But since we are configuring the queue in the context file , it is not neccessary to send it as a parameter value right ?!

Comment: What would be the configuration for jndiTemplate for ssl communication?